# Not enough permissions to access /me GET in LinkedIn Learning API

Tags: api, salesforce, linkedin-api

I connected **LinkedIn Learning courses with my Salesforce Org** and was able to connect.

But when I tried to get the users with courses assigned was unable to fetch.

I tried two of the end point URLs :

**https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me [For my users]
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/poeple [For other users]**

But I was unable to connect getting error **Not enough permissions to access: GET /me","status":403}**

Please let me know if someone has done before.